# Symfony 4 @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable() for form with collection type form

Tags: php, mysql, symfony4, symfony-forms, soft-delete

I have problem with soft delete item with form collection in Symfony framework

I want to add and remove items in relation with Symfony form collection, If I remove item from collection this item must soft deleted from relation records

with below image you can imagine relations

[image: product relation generated with Mysql workbench]

This is my form collections in Symfony forms

```
Main form
   +
   |
   ProductType+
   |          |
   |          |
   |          PackagesType+
   |                      |
   |                      |
   |                      PackageProductsType
   |
   |
   +
```

Package products add and removed with JS in frontend based on [Symfony example for form collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage)

my problem is when I remove completely from `package_product` with activating *orphanRemoval=true* in annotation of entity every thing work well but record removed completely and I want record soft deleted based on my propose, But when I change below function in `Package` Entity

```php
    public function removePackageProduct(PackageProduct $packageProduct): self
    {
        if ($this->packageProducts->contains($packageProduct)) {
            $this->packageProducts->removeElement($packageProduct);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($packageProduct->getPackage() === $this) {
                $packageProduct->setPackage(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

always in top function I get last record in `packageProducts` and when I remove this line `$packageProduct->setPackage(null);` to disable loosing data in record and replace it with `$packageProduct->setDeletedAt(new \Datetime());` to set deleted item, In saved records removed record delete from database and a new record added filled with last record data and deletedAt datetime.

For example:

`PackageProduct` records before delete first item:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| ID | Product_id | package_id | amount | deletedAt |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |         10 |          1 |      3 |           |
|  2 |         11 |          1 |      4 |           |
|  3 |         12 |          1 |      5 |           |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

`PackageProduct` records after delete first item:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| ID | Product_id | package_id | amount | deletedAt |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|  2 |         11 |          1 |      4 |           |
|  3 |         12 |          1 |      5 |           |
|  4 |         12 |          1 |      5 |2020-1-20..|
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

But I expected `PackageProduct` records after delete first item:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| ID | Product_id | package_id | amount | deletedAt |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |         10 |          1 |      3 |2020-1-20..|
|  2 |         11 |          1 |      4 |           |
|  3 |         12 |          1 |      5 |           |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

How can fix this to get expected result?

Comment: Do I correctly understand the problem: Instead of deleting doctrine collection entries, you only want to update their `deletedAt` field, but whenever you do that, the changed entry gets persisted as a new entity?

Comment: @Barthy Yes, exactly

Comment: The only change you made is changing the `setPackage()` to `setDeletedAt()`? Did you remove `removeElement()`?